# Docker container from image created from a windows machine gives error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, huawei-cloud

When I create a docker image and push to the SWR of Huawei cloud, the container fails to restart with error

```
libcontainer: container start initialization failed: standard_init_linux.go:224: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

When I do the same from a linux machine or a mac machine, it gives no issue and runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://davidcasr.medium.com/docker-standard-init-linux-go-211-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory-en-c0cb42edb295

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ahhh!...missed this. Thanks guys.